# How to show the Content of div in the middle of the div

Tags: css

I am using asp.net. I want to show the content of the div in the middle. but it showing the content in the top. my Div Is as follows:

```
    <div style=" height:100px; width:100px; float:left; background:#666666;">
     <span>about us</span>
    </div>
```

How can i show the content in the middle. I have used Margin and padding but it shows the result in the whole div not the content. How can i do this please help i am new to asp.net.

thank you

Comment: Avoid inline css rules as far as you can..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the display of div to table-cell, and then you can use vertical-align property as given

```
 <div style=" height:100px; width:100px; float:left; background:#666666; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle">
     <span>about us</span>
    </div>
```

check it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   <div style=" height:100px; width:100px; float:left; background:#666666;text-align:center">
     <span>about us</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align it horizontally, Bibhu's answer will do.

To align it vertically in the middle, add this to your style:

```
line-height: 100px;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove float:left and add text-align property and line-height property.

```
<div style=" height:100px; width:100px;background:#666666;text-align:center;line-height:100px;">
     <span >about us</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
height:100px; width:100px; background:#666666; line-height:100px;
```

Comment: Thank You For Your Kind Time and effort to solve my problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Refer - [how to align text vertical center in div with css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8865463)

It explains how to centralize text beautifully with many demos.